# How do i check if my fb app is banned?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm not sure whether my fb-app is banned by automated bot. Currently with PHP-SDK, getUser() returns 0 no matter what. It all used to be working fine till a few days before. I'm getting an access token but since getUSer() is always returning NULL, the app is not working. I didn;t have much of code changes except for opengraph meta-tags, like button and google +1 button in my webpage.

Is there any way i could check if my app is not banned? 
I haven't got any mail yet regarding this.
It doesn't show up in my list of apps even though i have used it recently.
But it shows up ins search.

Answer (score 0):

Log into Facebook with an account that is an administrator of your app
Then navigate to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps or more directly you could go to
`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{yourAppId}/summary`